# Substracting minutes from Time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string in date-time format "02/22/12 01:04"  (24 hour time format) I need to subtract 6 minutes from it. (like subtracting 1 minutes each time using loop) and store it in array all 6 different times. I need to do this in ruby 1.8.7. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

In rails, you can do this, though I am not sure which Gem in rails allows you to:

```
# to get 2012, use "02/22/2012"
# note this gives you the year 0012, not 2012.

my_date = "02/22/12 01:04".to_time
my_date_array = []
6.times do
  my_date -= 1.minute
  my_date_array.push(my_date.strftime("%D/%m/%Y %I:%M"))
end
```

I assumed from the Tags you listed that you need to do this in Rails.  Works in Rails 3+ for me, using Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: "02/22/12 01:04".to_time will help u a bit

Comment: Thank you @Jak.  user656213 indeed specified string input and I failed to address this.  Though I think the year is wrong, the string is as listed in the question.  I am going to update the answer using this suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is a really awefull job in ruby 1.8.7:

```
require 'time'
require 'date'

6.times.map { |i| Time.parse(DateTime.strptime("02/22/12 01:04", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").to_s) - i * 60}
# => [Wed Feb 22 02:04:00 +0100 2012, Wed Feb 22 02:03:00 +0100 2012, Wed Feb 22 02:02:00 +0100 2012, Wed Feb 22 02:01:00 +0100 2012, Wed Feb 22 02:00:00 +0100 2012, Wed Feb 22 01:59:00 +0100 2012]
```